# child container collapsing

Tags: css, html

I have a web page with one big container for the entire page. Inside that `<div>` I have another `<div>` with `float:left`. Then, floating to the right of that child `<div>` I have a second container that will contain other `<div>`s. The secondary container is collapsing. I have searched and tried other solutions, but they didn't solve anything. BTW this is an html5 page `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Any ideas?
CSS:

```
body {
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Hanuman;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bibletree {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#container2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 85%;
    background: gray;
    float: right;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="bibletree">
          stuff here
     </div>
     <div id="container2">
          there will be two other divs here as well. This one is collapsing.
     </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now give to `body` and `html height 100%`

As like this

```
body, html{
height:100%;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/zTVYBafv)***

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Can you provide an explanation why it works? I don't get it? Is the `#container2` div inheriting the height from the body or html tags? I thought it would inherit the height of the parent div.

Comment: @preahkumpii now more info check to this http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/comment-page-5/

Answer (score 0):

Does [This](http://jsfiddle.net/QNASS/) solve the problem?

(adding `overflow:hidden` to `#container2`'s rules?)